# CodeIgniter: Redirect URL with subdomain

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-routing

I am trying to redirect a subdomain URL to a controller method. Complete url is

```
http://subdomain.domain.com/urlofservice/servicename.svc
```

**Part1**
I have configured subdomain from hosting service's control panel. Which is redirecting `subdomain.domain.com` to `domain.com`

**Part2**

Configured route url on router.php as

```
$route['urlofservice/servicename.svc'] = "test/test3";
```

But when I try to hit the complete url, I get 404 error from the hosting service. 404 error is thrown from hosting server not from codeigniter.

Is there any problem with my seetting?
Should I change redirection setting in .htaccess or in server control panel? Right now server is throwing 404 error which means it's not even hitting the application yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use routes directly for subdomain. Use this in your `routes.php`

```
if (strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 'subdomain.domain.com')) {
   $route['urlofservice/servicename.svc'] = "test/test3";
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But right now url is not hitting the application, I am getting 404 from hosting server itself.

Comment: What is the need of subdomain, if you redirecting it to main domain?

Comment: Sorry. I wasn't sure about its configuration. I don't know if I have to do some configuration on .htaccess file or leave the redirect part blank.

Comment: @Himanshu, probably yes. I don't see any other option. I am not good with `mod_rewrite`.